# JOLT Transformation - Name new Element as Value of Array Element

Tags: json, jolt

i am not sure if this is possible with a jolt transformation. But i want to change a json with a random order to concrete names:

input json:

```
{
  "scheduler" : {
    "schedulerInfo" : {
      "usedCapacity" : 50.0,
      "queueName" : "root",
      "queues" : {
        "queue" : [ {
          "type" : "capacitySchedulerLeafQueueInfo",
          "usedCapacity" : 10.0,
          "queueName" : "jupyter"
        }, {
          "type" : "capacitySchedulerLeafQueueInfo",
          "usedCapacity" : 25.0,
          "queueName" : "spark"
          },
          {
          "type" : "capacitySchedulerLeafQueueInfo",
          "usedCapacity" : 15.0,
          "queueName" : "dremio"
          }
        } ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

desired outcome:

```
{
"rootUsedCapacity": 50.0,
"jupyterUsedCapacity": 10.0,
"sparkUsedCapacity": 25.0,
"dremioUsedCapacity":15.0
}
```

i know how to make it static, but i don´t know how to add the value of "queueName" to an new Attribute &value+UsedCapacity : &ArrayValue

Static Solution:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "scheduler": {
        "schedulerInfo": {
          "usedCapacity": "rootUsedCapacity",
          "queues": {
            "queue": {
              "0": {
                "usedCapacity": "jupyterUsedCapacity"
              },
              "1": {
                "usedCapacity": "sparkUsedCapacity"
              },
              "2": {
                "usedCapacity": "dremioUsedCapacity"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Concat the queueName with UsedCapacity string, and then shift the newly created node with the usedCapacity,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "scheduler": {
        "schedulerInfo": {
          "queues": {
            "queue": {
              "*": {
                "queueNameNew": "=concat(@(1,queueName),'UsedCapacity')"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "scheduler": {
        "schedulerInfo": {
          "usedCapacity": "rootUsedCapacity",
          "queues": {
            "queue": {
              "*": {
                "usedCapacity": "@(1,queueNameNew)"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```